# Error 1054 : Unknown column 'numberof_bouquets_fta' in 'field list' - PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sqlyog

I have already scrolled through all the related answers but haven't got exact answer I wanted.

I have to insert the data on click of Submit button in table.

**Issue 1: `numberof_bouquets_fta` field was missing :** First time when I was submitting the form `numberof_bouquets_fta` field was genuinely missing in my table, so then I altered the table and added the field.  *So here issue one resolves.*

**Issue 2: `numberof_bouquets_fta` field is actually there but still is showing the 1054 Error :** I have dropped the column and added it twice but still I am facing this error. Also, I have tried to insert the same query directly from PHPMyAdmin, there it works just fine.

Is there any caching issue from server side or CI issue? I don't know what I am doing incorrectly here because the same code is running fine on Dev environment.

Below is the query which is throwing error :

```
INSERT INTO `tblcounteragreements` 
(`reason_type`, `remarks`,
`original_agreementid`, `agreement_stage`,
`agreementno`, `total_exicute`, `rio_base_usertype`, 
`dpo_id`, `rio_id`, `rio_announcement_date`, `rio_effective_date`, `rio_valid_from`,
`rio_valid_to`, `agreement_date`, 
`valid_from`, `valid_to`, `target_market`, `number_of_paychanels`,
`numberof_fta_chanels`, `numberof_bouquets`,
`numberof_bouquets_fta`, `additional_remarks`,
`confirmation_given`, `agreement_with_usertype`, `brodcaster_id`, 
`broadcaster_name`, `dpo_name`,
`submitted_by_usertype`, `submitted_by`,
`agreement_type`, `lco_id`,
`createdby`, `createdon`, 
`createdbyip`, `modifiedby`,
`modifiedon`, `modifiedbyip`, `status`)
VALUES ('Discrepancy in Channels/Bouquets', 'testing',
'2969', '2', 'DI0978/Agr/6juneagr1',
'12', 'Broadcaster', '1333', '107', 
'2020-06-01', '2020-07-01',
'2020-06-01', '2020-06-30', '2020-06-01',
'2020-06-01', '2020-06-30', 'sds', '2', '3', '1', '1', 
'', 'Y', '3', '1332', 'TRAI Farheen RA',
'TRAI souvik', '2', '1332', 'RIO', NULL,
'1509', '2020-06-05 22:59:32', 
'106.215.74.44', '', '', '', 1);
```

Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: does `INSERT INTO tblcounteragreements (numberof_bouquets_fta) VALUES ('the_fta_value')` work?

Comment: it works manually, this whole query is executing fine manually.

Comment: What is the result of `show columns from tblcounteragreements`? Is `numberof_bouquets_fta` present?

Comment: yes this column is present in table ..

Comment: Have you crosschecked the database name in config? Is it the right one you are referring to?

Comment: @Drk I was referring to wrong database. Thank you for pointing it out.